# How do I get a Discord bot to read data from a specific range of a Google Sheet?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, discord, discord.js, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to get a discord bot to lookup data from a Google sheet?

**Example Situation:**
If the Discord bot is presented with a command "!points Bob", the bot would lookup the google sheet for "Bob" and return the number of points that Bob has.

I would assume that I would use the module google-spreadsheet but I am new. Is there anyone that can help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, i havnt tested this yet!
I used the `googleapis` npm-package for this.

```
/*
Assuming your table is something like this:
 |------------------|
 | Player  | Points |
 |------------------|
 | Player1 | 0      |
 | Player2 | 100    |
 |------------------|
*/
function checkPoints(auth,name) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });

        sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
            spreadsheetId: '<your spreadsheetid>',
            range: '<Your Points sheetname>!A2:B', // A2 because i assume you got a title like "Name/Username" etc.
        }, (err, res) => {
            if (err) return console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
            let list = [];
            for(let i = 0; i < res[0].length; i++){ //Loop throw all Players
                if(res[0][i] == name){
                    resolve(res[1][i]); //Returns the Points of the Player
                }
            }
        }
        );
    });
}
```

To use this function you must pass the auth from the api (take a look at the documentation of the `googleapis` Package) and a name. The function returns a promise, and there you go, like i said i havent tested this within a discord bot yet.

```
checkPoints(auth,name).then(points =>{
    console.log("Points  of player " + name + ": " + points);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create your discord bot to parse these commands and pipe them to the API.

To access the API, you have to authorize it.

Refer to the [Quick-start Guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) to learn how to do so.

After you have your application authorized, then it's all a matter of calling the method based on your chat input.

Hope this helps!